# "OAuthException","message":"Error validating application."

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, validating

up until 4 days ago this was working just fine, now I keep receiving an error when trying to post a youtube video on my friends (or even my own) wall.

Reading user ids from list.txt and send them a video
Posting video to user id: me
{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"Error validating application."}}

I am getting the same error with an application which i created on a friends facebook account when trying to do the same thing.

Does anyone have an idea why this is and what I can do to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: Same here, our website, has suddenly started receiving these errors out of now where. The api we are using is /me

Answer (score 1):

I started getting this problem for some of my users on my app recently.  It was because my database field for storing oauth tokens was limited to 100 characters, which in the past has been long enough for facebook oauth tokens.  Newer tokens are sometimes longer than that.

Just a guess...

Answer (score 0):

I have suddenly started getting this on working code too. I have traced the API URL the PHP SDK is calling and it does have an access token in. The PHP SDK errors with 'An active access token must be used...' and calling the URL it called manually results in 'Error validating application.'